# How to Validate a form in within the same page and when there are no errors send it to another page for further registration?

Tags: php, forms, validation

Okay. I have yet another easy problem which I can't solve. I am working with PHP and I am working on a form to be validated by PHP. I have validated the form in another page containing the same elements. That's the

```
 <form name = "Order Form" action = "<?php echo    htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method = "post">
```

but now the problem arises is that, when we have validated the form and there are no more errors, how to send the data for further registration in other pages. Assuming that Javascript is off I have to use this method. Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: You can store value in session for that.

Comment: There are several ways to do this however you are not showing us anything. What are you trying to register that needs to carry data over multiple form submit? Can you provide an example of the multiple forms you have? Why are you not inserting the data to a database once its validated and registered?

Comment: I just validated the form. Now I don't know where to go when the form elements have no user input error

Comment: probably you want `header("Location :next_page.php");`

Comment: so you are saying when there are no errors in the form I would be redirecting them?

Comment: I thought you want the same as you said *how to send the data for further registration in other pages*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `session` to store some data for a short time such as registration process example:

```
<?php session_start();

if(noerror){
$_SESSION['username']=$username;
//similarly do for more
header("Location:next_page.php");
}
else{
//show error
}
```

**Note:** Alternatively You can also use hidden input but I will discourage that as for security purpose you need to re-validate that.

**Update:**

To check if an error has occurred or not no need to count them simply use an variable called `$noerror` and initialize it with `TRUE` and as soon as an error occurs set it to `false` then simply put it in `if($noerror)` at last.
If you want to display error message store them in an array like `$error_log`
*example:*

```
if(error_in_username){
$noerror=false;
$error_log['username']="Invalid Username";
}
```

Comment: so you're saying I am going to count the number of errors.    
         If count($error)=0 { $_SESSION['username']=$username; 
header("Location:next_page.php");

Comment: Updated My answer check it out

Comment: I didn't get that code "if(error in username)" how am I supposed to get if an user has error or not?

Comment: Using validation. first validate input if invalid then run this code.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to below link.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_url_email.asp

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: so how does this help? I want to get to another page

Comment: if(empty($nameErr) || empty($emailErr) || empty($websiteErr) || empty($genderErr)) { header('location:yourpage.php'); }. Please check variables in your case.

Answer (score -1):

On your validation 'page' which should be a controller of sorts, if validation is successful, load the step2 page with the previous form data in hidden inputs.

OR

After successful validation of step1, save the data already into database (could be a temp table), and then proceed to step2 with the id of the entry you just saved. On submission of step2, you can merge the step2 data with the data of the entry that was saved in the database, and proceed to step3 if necessary. etc.

If you simply want to get to another page, the basic logic is:

```
if(validation_success) 
{
    header("Location: step2.php");
} else {
    show_errors();
}
```

Comment: `step2 page with the previous form data in hidden inputs` not a good example and can be easily manipulated since its past validation so means I can change it as I wish!

Comment: No my question was how to escape the page where the form is being validated for step two? Should I be redirecting them or there is another better way?

Comment: I stand corrected by Prix re: hidden inputs. Updated my reply about going to another page. Redirect is the common method, if you are doing something fancy you could load the step2 page with ajax, but probably over your level...

Comment: seems resonable, on step2.php I would be carrying the session variables and then store in the database